# Avoid multiple if clauses to call different methods

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, selector

I have a similar code structure to this one:

```
if !checkFirstName(firstName: firstNameField.text!)  {
   firstNameField.text = "foo"
   return false
}      
firstNameField.text = "bar"

if !checkLastName(lastName: lastNameField.text!)  {
   lastNameField.text = "foo"
   return false
}    
lastNameField.text = "bar"

...
```

The problem here is the fact that I have to do several more checks, but they differ only by function name and the `UITextField` I am working on.

I do want them to be part of a single `for` loop or `map`, but it seems like I couldn't make it work by using `Selector()`, somewhat similar to the following:

```
let functionNames = ["FirstName", "LastName", ...]
let fields = ["FirstName": firstNameField, "LastName": lastNameField, ...]

...

for name in functionNames {
    let sel = Selector("check" + name + ":")

    if !view.perform(sel) {
       fields[name].text = "foo"
       return false 
    }

    fields[name].text = "bar"
    return true
}
```

`Selector()` is not recommended in Swift and, even if it may work, I want to avoid it.

Should I research further into making `Selector()` work or is this whole duplication problem an architectural problem? In any case, how can I avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are first-class objects in Swift, which mean you can pass them like variables too. Instead of building the function name dynamically, associate them with the `UITextField` in a tuple.

Assuming you have these functions:

```
func check (firstName: String) -> Bool {
    // ...
}

func check (lastName: String) -> Bool {
    // ....
}
```

You can loop them like this:

```
// checks is an array of tuples. Each tuple has 2 components:
// a UITextField and a function which takes a String and return a Bool
let checks: [(field: UITextField, checker: (String) -> Bool)] = [
    (firstNameField, check(firstName:)),
    (lastNameField , check(lastName:))
]

for c in checks {
    guard c.checker(c.field.text!) else {
        c.field.text = "foo"
        return false
    }

    c.field.text = "bar"
}
```

Comment: If I am right, you are telling me to leverage the power of polymorphism. I think this will work, but I will give you the concrete answer tomorrow.

Comment: The proper nomenclature is *function overload*, not polymorphism. The Swift compiler will generate different names for `check(firstName:)` and `check(lastName:)` using name mangling. Having said that, you can name these functions anything you'd like, like `checkFirstName` and `check(lastName:)`

Comment: It worked and I think this is the most appropriate method to solve my problem. I am also open to even more elegant ways.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to get all the text fields from your view, then continue with generic function.

(I have not compiled below code.)

```
func getAllTextFields() -> [UITextField] {
    var results:[UITextField] = []
    for subview in view.subviews {
        results += getAllTextFields(in: subview)
        if subview.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
            if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
                results.append(textField)
            }
        }
    }
    return results
}


func YourFuncName() -> Bool {
  var allTextFields = getAllTextFields()
  var returnValue = true
  for textField in allTextFields {
    if !checkTextField(text: textField.text) {
        textField.text = “foo”
        returnValue = false
        break
    } else {
        textField.text = “bar”
    }
  }
  return returnValue

}

func checkTextField (text :String ) -> Bool {
//Your checking func body goes here
}
```

**Modified: I am able to perform "perform selector"**

[image]

Comment: The If clauses (or Switch) will move inside the `checkTextField` if I do this.

Comment: What exactly are you checking in checkFirstName and checkLastName? Are they relatable? Or is it just null string check?

Comment: FirstName and LastName are, by the mistake of this example, relatable, but the next check will involve checkCountry, which has a different set of rules. In other words, `checkTextField` will not be a general function, sadly.

Comment: I have edited the solution. Can you refer and tell me why you were not able to do "perform selector". Or am I missing something from your question?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Seems like a `Selector()` answer works here as well. I had not initialized the Helper class (`MyClass` in your example) and was using static methods that would crash somehow

Comment: Please vote up if you find my solution helpful   :P ;)